# How to test remove element in linked list?

Tags: java, junit, linked-list

I have a Linked list below:

[image]

if I want to remove an element with this code:

```
 int a = list1.remove(0);
```

so what verification code should I include to make sure this operation works correctly?

Thank you and hope to receive answer from you soon.

Comment: You may want to call `isEmpty()` first.

Comment: Do you want mock remove method?

Comment: Using JUnit what about `assertNotNull(a)`

Comment: Well... Assert that the list looks like you expect after you remove the element. E.g. if it contains 1,2,3 and you remove the 2, it contains 1,3.

Comment: @xetra11, you just check only `a`, it's not enough. You have to make sure your linked list already removed element.

Comment: @MinhBui you're right

Comment: @coder What I wonder is that you are about to test a foreign library - that's actually not your "job" - the testing is the job of the author of this library (java std lib here)

Comment: @xetra who is to say that this "linked list" is an instance of `java.util.LinkedList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test your operation with all cases below:

1. Verify that `a` has value.
2. Check get(-1) to make sure that cause an index out of bound exception.
3. Check get(0) to return value is 21.
4. Calling list at size to check to.

Hope it would help.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

The method `LinkedList#remove(int)` **removes** the element at the **given position** (in your case index `0`, so the first element), here is its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove-int-).

After removal all other elements **move to the front** (index `1` becomes index `0` and so on). As a note: This comes of no additional cost due to the character of a `LinkedList`.

---

### Testing

There are several possibilities to test correctness (for a JUnit Test for example):

- Test if the method removes something at all
- Test if the method removed the correct element (the first)
- Test if all other elements moved to the front (indices changed)
- Test if the method returns the removed element (according to its documentation)
- Test if the method correctly handles empty lists (throwing an exception)
- Test if the method correctly removes the element if its `null`

---

### Examples

Here are some implementations for all mentioned cases:

```
@Test
public void testSizeChange() {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

    Assert.assertEquals(5, list.size());
    list.remove(0);
    Assert.assertEquals(4, list.size());
}

@Test
public void testRemovedCorrectElement() {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

    Assert.assertTrue(list.contains(1));
    list.remove(0);
    Assert.assertFalse(list.contains(1));
}

@Test
public void testElementsMoved() {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

    list.remove(0);

    Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
    for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
        Assert.assertTrue(iter.hasNext());
        Assert.assertEquals(i, iter.next());
    }
    Assert.assertFalse(iter.hasNext());
}

@Test
public void testReturnRemovedValue() {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

    Assert.assertEquals(1, list.remove(0));
}

@Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
public void testHandleEmpty() {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.remove(0);
}

@Test
public void testRemoveNull() {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(null, 2, 3, 4, 5));

    Assert.assertNull(list.remove(0));
}
```

Note that if your `LinkedList` is not `java.util.LinkedList` but an own implementation you may need to modify the later examples a bit according to **your documentation** and needs.

Comment: "The method LinkedList#remove(int) removes the element at the first position (with index 0)" so what is the parameter for?

Comment: Note that `new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2))` is an easier way to construct the lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it by simply calling size method on linked list. Then do assertequals on expected size of linked list.

```
assertEquals(EXPECTED_SIZE, list1.size())
```

Expected Size would be an int value  which would be 1 value less than initial size.

To assert if actual value is removed you can assert on contains

```
assertFalse(list1.contains(65))
```

Here 65 is the actual value which was removed.

Comment: you should check index=0 and index =-1 as well

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are all correct - but it would still be possible to create a wrong list implementation that passes all these specific tests - but contains some obscure bugs.

This is a scenario where test frameworks based on the [QuickCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck) idea have certain merit. Instead of writing various test cases manually - you rather *specify* the rules/contract that must be true for your operations to QuickCheck. And then the framework creates random tests - and when it finds something that violates your rules, it will even reduce the input to the "minimum" required to show the problem.

I am not saying that QuickCheck is the "better" solution here - but it is definitely a good companion to the kind of testing that the other answers point you to.